# How do I get parent category from sub category id?

Tags: mysql

Here is my `categories` table

[image]

MySQL statement

```
SELECT
maincat.cat_id,
maincat.cat_name,
maincat.cat_parent,
subcat.cat_id,
subcat.cat_name,
subcat.cat_parent
FROM
categories maincat
INNER JOIN categories subcat ON subcat.cat_id = 2
```

Let's say my current category is `Men Clothes` and `cat_id = 2`. How do I retrieve the parent category name correctly because with current statement the result is showing 4 `Personal Items` ?

Update :

```
$get_cat = $db->get_results("
            SELECT
            maincat.cat_id,
            maincat.cat_name,
            maincat.cat_parent,
            subcat.cat_id,
            subcat.cat_name,
            subcat.cat_parent
            FROM
            categories maincat
            INNER JOIN categories subcat ON subcat.cat_id = 2
            ");
foreach ( $get_cat as $cat )
{
echo '<option value="'.$cat->cat_id.'">'.$cat->cat_name.'</option>';
}
```

Current ouput

```
<option value="1">Personal Items</option>
<option value="1">Personal Items</option>
<option value="1">Personal Items</option>
<option value="1">Personal Items</option>
<option value="1">Personal Items</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `JOIN`, even when it's a self-Join, you need to add a condition for the Join. Here it should be `ON subcat.cat_parent = maincat.cat_id`:

```
SELECT
  maincat.cat_id,
  maincat.cat_name,
  maincat.cat_parent,
  subcat.cat_id         AS subcat_id,
  subcat.cat_name       AS subcat_name,
  subcat.cat_parent     AS subcat_parent
FROM
  categories maincat
    INNER JOIN 
  categories subcat 
      ON subcat.cat_parent = maincat.cat_id
WHERE 
  subcat.cat_id = 2
```

The `INNER JOIN` should be changed into `LEFT OUTER JOIN` if you want the query to also work for categories that do not have a parent (`NULL` in `cat_parent` column).

Comment: Hmmm.. the result is `Men Clothes`. How about if `cat_id = 2` I want the result is `Personal Items`

Comment: ?? The result is both the subcategory (Mens Clothes) and parent category (Personal Items).

Comment: Oh, I think you need to rename (alias) the columns that have identical names with different ones. See my edit.

Comment: Hmm.. If without `WHERE subcat.cat_id = 2` result will return `Personal Items` four time because of the sub cat has 4 items. I think the answer is `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You don't need a group by. This will return 1 row only (or 0 if there is no parent).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8520/discussion-between-unknown-error-and-ypercube)

Comment: Such a complicated query to get the parent category when you know its ID? I doubt this is performant.

Comment: You don't know the id of the parent. And this will be quite efficient, with proper indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be so complicated to do such a simple query:

```
SELECT name
FROM categories
WHERE cat_id = cat_parent
```

`cat_parent` is defined in the code, of course. In this case, it may be `1`.

Comment: this is will return `Men Clothes` not the `Personal Items`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_parent FROM categories WHERE cat_id = 2
```

Comment: this is will return `Men Clothes` not the `Personal Items`